# Feature detection is not working for events in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, dom-events, browser-feature-detection

I'm trying to write a cross-browser event addition method but it's not working in IE at all, here's the code :

***index.html***

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>

    <body>            
        <script type="text/javascript" src="helper.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    </body>

</html>
```

***helper.js***

```
var eventUtil = {

    add : function(el, type, fn){
        if(typeof(addEventListener) !== "undefined"){
            el.addEventListener(type, fn, false);
        } else if (typeof(attachEvent) !== "undefined"){
            el.attachEvent("on"+type, fn);  
        } else {
            el["on"+type] = fn;
        }
    }    
}
```

***script.js***

```
(function(){
    var printMsg= function(){            
        document.write("hello");
    };
    eventUtil.add(document.body, "click" , printMsg);
}());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do:

```
add : function(el, type, fn){
    if(typeof(el.addEventListener) !== "undefined"){
        el.addEventListener(type, fn, false);
    } else if (typeof(el.attachEvent) !== "undefined"){
        el.attachEvent("on"+type, fn);  
    } else {
        el["on"+type] = fn;
    }
```

As you had it with:

```
    if(typeof(addEventListener) !== "undefined"){
```

that will always be `undefined` as `addEventListener` is not a global variable/function it's a method on the element.

Comment: actually,  addEventListener is defined if window.addEventListener is defined.

Comment: @kennebec - that is no different than what I said - I'm not sure what new information you're adding.  `window.addEventListener` is the same as a global variable/function named `addEventListener` because the global javascript namespace in a browser is `window`.